# check whether the empty string exist in an input field

Tags: jquery

how to check whether an input form has empty string? I tried use the code below but didn't work.

`e.which == 13` is to catch whether the user press the enter key, secondly !== "" is to prevent data input if there is nothing typed.. but why didn't work? the logic seem ok.. the first one worked, the second didn't..

```
if(e.which == 13 && $(inputBar) !== ""){
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be checking for `$(inputBar).val()` not just `$(inputBar)` that will just return the `object` itself not the `value` of the text in the input box

Answer (score 0):

```
if(e.which ==13 && $('#Selector for input box').val().length == 0 ) {
       //do something
}
```

On doing `$('#Selector for input box')` jquery will return the object and not the value inside it. So to access the value you have to use `val()` function and then check the length

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by

```
if(e.which ==13 && $(inputBar).val() != '' ) {
   //code here 
}
```

or

```
if(e.which ==13 && $(inputBar).val().length == 0 ) {
   //code here 
}
```

Thats All